# Opencart Currency Symbol

Tags: opencart2.3

What is the problem ?
[image]

Euro symbol does not appear.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How did you enter those values? Are those values stored in a non-unicode database column? It seems pretty obvious that unicode values for symbols, umlaut characters and accent characters are treated as ascii text.

Comment: character set = utf-8 , collate : utf-8-general_ci

Answer (score 0):

**This may be the reason**

Currency have two symbols symbol right and symbol left. To make support for both types of currency you need to include both symbols.
You forgot to include following code.

`<?php echo $currency['symbol_right'] ?>`

Your full code looks:

```
<?php echo $currency['symbol_left']; ?> <?php echo $currency['title']; ?> <?php echo $currency['symbol_left']; ?>
```